# How define and setting parameters in Hibernate Query Language (HQL)?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I need to know what i have to write inside the text of an Hibernate Query Language query to define a parameter and then how i assign a value to this parameter. For example, look at this code:

```
nhSession
.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO historiccard SELECT * FROM card WHERE game_id={0}")
.SetParameter(0, lobby.getPK());
```

What i have to write after game_id=?. After that, is that right the way in that i'm assigning the value to the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

One way:-

```
nhSession
.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO historiccard SELECT * FROM card WHERE game_id=:id")
.SetInt32("id", lobby.getPK());
```

You don't need to add single quotes etc for strings, dates, etc, just use a :varname

You can assign values using

```
.SetDateTime("varname", DateTime.Now)
.SetInt64("varname", 12345678)
.SetString("varname", "rippo")
```

You can also chain these together.

Comment: Just wondering why this has been down voted? To learn where I where wrong please can you give a comment. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Sorry, i don´t know what happened. Your comment was very useful to me. Thanks.